# Check new day using Shared preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have created an app. I have Put a button in my app. When I click on the button the click time is saved to shared preferences.

```
private void saveClickTime() {
        String str = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
        SharedPreferences.Editor localEditor = this.sp.edit();
        localEditor.putString("mTime", str);
        localEditor.commit();
    }
```

Now I want to create a method `isTimeToClick()` when a new day starts. Like today is 3rd October. On 12.00 Pm 4th October will starts. I want that when a new days starts the method will start.

```
 private boolean isTimeToClick() {
        SimpleDateFormat localSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        try
        {
            // here I have to call the method but I don't know what should I use. can anyone help me?
        }
        catch (Exception localException) {}
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store time in milliseconds and retrieve it to create a date instance from shared preferences and compare the dates.

```
private void saveClickTime() {
    sp.edit().putLong("mTime", System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
}

private boolean isTimeToClick() {
    Date oldDate = new Date(sp.getLong("mTime", System.currentTimeMillis()));
    GregorianCalendar oldCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    oldCalendar.setTime(oldDate);
    Calendar newCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    return newCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE) != oldCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE) ||
            newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) != oldCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) ||
            newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) != oldCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

Comment: i know that . but i don't understanding how to compare the dates :(

Comment: show i use this ?     oldDate.compareTo(newDate);
            if (oldDate.compareTo(newDate)>0);

Comment: No. use date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(),etc. if they are same, it is the same day otherwise it is a different day.